# How to append a URL to the end of my string in php?

Tags: php

I tried this: `$client->createRequest('GET', 'cdn.api.twitter.com/1/urls/count.json?url="' . $url . '"'),`
 it works but even then I get this: %22http//facebook.com;%22/. Yes, the URL is encoded too.

**edit** I fixed it. :) Had to leave out the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single quotes inhibit substitution. Either use double quotes, or close the quotes before performing the concatenation and open them again after.

[Relevant documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: Why would you put double quotes in the query string?

Comment: Okay, I fixed it actually :)